# Why does this while loop end? node5 is not NoneType. (Traversing Linked Lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, linked-list, nodes

Code below. I understand conceptually that the loop ends because self.next of the final node = `None`, but we're checking to see that `node != None`, and `type(node5)` returns `__main__.LinkedListNode`, which is not `None`. So how does `node != None` ever return `False`, ending the while loop?

```
class LinkedListNode():

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None #This is the next point, is initially None

    def traverseList(self):
        node = self #Start at the Head Node
        while node != None:
            print(node.value) #Access the node value
            node = node.next #Move to the next link in the list

#Create nodes for list
node1 = LinkedListNode('Mon')
node2 = LinkedListNode('Tues')
node3 = LinkedListNode('Wed')
node4 = LinkedListNode('Thurs')
node5 = LinkedListNode('Fri')

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = node4
node4.next = node5

node1.traverseList()

type(node5)
```

Comment: Found an answer yet? As @CDJB said the issue is with node5 having a `next` of `None` and that you attempt to apply a conditional to `None`. To avoid this, inside your `for` loop, you could  put `if node.next is None: break` to break out of the loop once a node with a `next` of `None` is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking if `type(node5) = None`, your while loop checks if `node != None`.

At the final iteration, `node` holds `node5`, so `print(node.value)` prints `Fri`, `node = node.next` sets `node` to `None`, as we never set `node5`'s `next` attribute, and then the while loop terminates.

Comment: Of course, I wasn't looking hard enough at the `else` statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the final iteration `node` gets set to `None` because `node5` has a `next` of `None`. You can avoid this by breaking out of the loop when this condition is encountered...

```
def traverseList(self):
        node = self #Start at the Head Node
        while node != None:
            print(node.value) #Access the node value
            if node.next is None:
                break
            else:
                node = node.next #Move to the next link in the list
```